# incorrect conversion of String into date format

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to format a string into specific date format but there is some problem in conversion. In converted string month is always coming "January". Following is the code snippet:

```
    String date = "30/10/2012-11:11:11";
    DateFormat dateForm = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy-hh:mm:ss");

    try {
       System.out.println(dateForm.parse(date));
    } 
    catch (ParseException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am not able to get the reason behind this.
Please suggest.

Comment: Replace `dd/mm/yyyy` with `dd/MM/yyyy` and [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, you should use `MM` for months - and I strongly suspect you *always* want to use `HH` for hours, instead of `hh`. `HH` is the 24 hour clock; `hh` is the 12 hour clock, usually used in conjunction with an AM/PM designator.

Finally, you should consider what time zone and locale you want your `SimpleDateFormat` to use. Even in this case where there aren't any month or day names, I'd still specify the locale explicitly, to make it clear that you're *not* trying to use any localized data.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
// TODO: Set the time zone appropriately
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `MM` instead of `mm` for the date portion of your format string. `mm` is for minutes, not months.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

Please use `"dd/MM/yyyy-hh:mm:ss"`

Comment: The hh is almost certainly inappropriate.

Comment: agree if he meant for 24 hr format (which seems as he's not using am/pm), thanks