# Date format parsing in android from April 18 2016 10:41 AM to 04/18/2016 10:41

Tags: android, date, parsing, datetime

I am trying to parse `April 18 2016 10:41 AM` to `04/18/2016 10:41`. Here is my code

```
private String dateFormat(String strCurrentDate) throws ParseException {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("mmmm dd yyyy hh:mm Z");
        Date newDate = null;
        newDate = format.parse(strCurrentDate);
        format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
        String date = format.format(newDate);
        Log.d("DATE_FORMATE_TESTING", date);
        return date;

    }
```

But it gives the following errors

```
04-18 10:41:43.834 7526-7526/gps.clock.com W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "April 18 2016 01:41 PM" (at offset 0)
04-18 10:41:43.834 7526-7526/gps.clock.com W/System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
04-18 10:41:43.834 7526-7526/gps.clock.com W/System.err:     at gps.clock.com.MainActivity.dateFormat(MainActivity.java:441)
04-18 10:41:43.834 7526-7526/gps.clock.com W/System.err:     at gps.clock.com.MainActivity.access$500(MainActivity.java:70)
04-18 10:41:43.834 7526-7526/gps.clock.com W/System.err:     at gps.clock.com.MainActivity$1$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:303)
```

Can anyone tell me how should I fix it? Why it is showing `Unparseable date`. How should I parse it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using Marshmallow?

Comment: You have lowercase `m`s for the month in the first pattern. They should be uppercase. And the character for am/pm is `a`, not `Z`. Please refer to the [`SimpleDateFormat` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [incorrect conversion of String into date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698165/incorrect-conversion-of-string-into-date-format)

Comment: @MikeM. I tried with MMMM instead of mmmm. But still I a geting the same error.

Comment: Did you change the `Z` as well?

Comment: @MikeM. no I didn't changed it. But it worked for me when I replaced Z with a. Can you please tell me what does it mean?

Comment: The `Z` character represents the time zone, which your date `String` doesn't have. It has am/pm, though, which is represented by the `a` character. Refer to the [`SimpleDateFormat` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for the available pattern characters and their meanings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code

```
    String strCurrentDate = "April 18 2016 10:41 AM";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm a");
    Date newDate = null;
    try {
        newDate = format.parse(strCurrentDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
    String date = format.format(newDate);
    System.out.print(date);
```

Comment: yes this worked for me. I will accept this answer. Can you please tell me what is the difference between a and Z that is in the SimpleDateFormate("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm a")?

Comment: 'a' is used to represent AM or PM, where as 'Z' (Zulu time)represents TimeZone, So it wasn't able to parse.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to tweak your original format string.

`SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("mmmm dd yyyy hh:mm Z");`

Should be

`SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy hh:mm a");`

Answer (score 0):

In java date formatting `m` and `M` both have different meaning. `m` is used to parse *minutes* while `M` is used to parse *month*.

In your example you are parsing month with lower case `m` and that causes error. As suggested by @Mike M. change your `m`s with upper case.